# Installing 'metasm' on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos

I've tried installing metasm (disassembler, debugger) on Mac OS X 10.9, but I can't seem to run the application with the GUI interface. I used home-brew and macports to install ruby, gtk2, gtk+ etc. as well as their dependencies.

When I tried running:

```
ruby metasm/samples/disassemble-gui.rb
```

the following was outputted:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- metasm (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from disassemble-gui.rb:27:in `<main>
```

I know nothing about Ruby; any advice? The metasm site says the normal response is for a GUI menu to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
gem install metasm
```

or

```
 sudo gem install metasm
```

Comment: I went into the installation directory of the gem installed using the command given, tried 'ruby gui.rb' and it says 'No GUI Ruby binding installed - please install libgtk2-ruby.' However, I already installed gtk+ with home-brew, and gtk2 with macports.

Comment: I tried gem install gtk2, but I think there's a problem with clang. Going to install the real gcc...